# Can't name a folder 'NUL' in windows

Tags: windows-8.1

Why when I Try to create a folder whith name = **nul** i get the following message:

> the specified device name is invalid

Comment: Know limit from backward DOS compatability. Same for folders such as con, lpt, ...

Comment: can you explain more please

Comment: Linked to the post answering it for CON, PRN, AUX, **NUL**, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9.     Summary: these keywords are used by Windows internally and are reserved Keywords.

Comment: So those name are used by windows so if I use one of them a confict will occure ???

Comment: Correct.  They were used in DOS, were used in DOS with the windows shell (sio windows 2, 3, 95, ..) and are still used/reserved in a modern setup.